# Gaps in histogram for geometric distribution

Tags: probability, histogram, geometric-distribution

I'm attempting an assignment in which we're supposed to write a function to simulate a geometric distribution with $p=0.03$. While plotting a histograms for about $100000$ simulations of the function, I got these:

[image]

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import random

def simulateGeo(p=0.03):
    n = 1
    while(random() >= p):
        n += 1
    return n

simresults = np.zeros(100000)

for i in range(100000):
    simresults[i] = simulateGeo()

pd.Series(simresults).hist(bins=200)
```

I'm just curious - what's the reason for these (seemingly regularly-spaced) gaps / spikes?

Comment: The geometric distribution is discrete but your histogram bins don't perfectly line up with the integer-spacing of the original variable. Histograms are suited for continuous variables rather than discrete ones. If you use them on discrete variables (rather than choosing a more suitable display), it can work, but you must choose your bin origin and bin size with some care rather than relying on defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in python `hist` sometimes bins tend to "cluster" and then for one value you will have observations from many values

**example:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
q = np.random.choice([0,1,2], 1000)
plt.hist(q, bins=2)
plt.hist(q, bins=3)
plt.show()
```

you will get the idea from plot yourself

Comment: Ah.. so it's an artifact due to the way Python plots histograms. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @ShirishKulhari yup, remember to set number of bins properly (as divisor of number of unique values in your data), or just cut the tail of distribution

Comment: @ShirishKulhari it's more problem of algorithm counting bins, you can always count them yourself